# Need a help in query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a hierarchical tree table structure .How can i get the left tree and right tree .

```
1   a   NULL
2   b   1
3   c   1
4   d   2
5   e   2
6   f   3
7   g   3
8   h   4
9   i   4
10  j   5
11  k   5
12  l   6
```

If i have the id of a ie 1 .how can i get the tree of b and c

i am expecting the tree under b as

```
2   b   
4   d   
5   e   
8   h   
9   i   
10  j   
11  k
```

Here i an following adjacency model only  i am going .I am not looking for nested model.
This mit be a duplicate question .

Comment: Could you please try to rephrase your question. At least to me, it doesn't make much sense at all...

Comment: please make it more clear what is what. If the columns are fields, give them a name to reflect that. Also I see that the first block is a sample database situation, but what is the second block? Is it what you want to get? Is it something else?
Also try restating what it is what you want to get, possibly with an example in your sample database situation. As long as I don't know what you are asking, I can't answer your question.

Comment: I'm guessing the columns are: node id, node key and parent node id. It seems to be a map of a b-tree to a DB. I suspect you might want to load the tree back into a tree structure and use ordinary tree algorithms to achieve your needs.

Comment: hello dave how can i achieve that ordinary tree algorithms.is there any materials to read.I am also expecting the same . and i have a doubt.If i follow nested model for this .And i have 1 lakh record .Whether it may cause any problem to update that much of columns

Answer (score 1):

this will return the tree structure for parent 1

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Val VARCHAR(MAX),
        ParentID INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val,ParentID) SELECT 1, 'a', NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val,ParentID) SELECT 2, 'b', 1
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val,ParentID) SELECT 3, 'c', 1
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val,ParentID) SELECT 4, 'd', 2
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val,ParentID) SELECT 5, 'e', 2
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val,ParentID) SELECT 6, 'f', 3
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val,ParentID) SELECT 7, 'g', 3
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val,ParentID) SELECT 8, 'h', 4
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val,ParentID) SELECT 9, 'i', 4
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val,ParentID) SELECT 10, 'j', 5
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val,ParentID) SELECT 11, 'k', 5
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val,ParentID) SELECT 12, 'l', 6

DECLARE @ParentID INT

SET @ParentID = 1

;WITH TreeSelect AS(
        SELECT  ID,
                Val
        FROM    @Table
        WHERE   ParentID = @ParentID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.ID,
                t.Val
        FROM    @Table t INNER JOIN
                TreeSelect ts ON t.ParentID = ts.ID
)
SELECT  *
FROM    TreeSelect
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need are CTE (Common Table Expressions)

This kind of recursive CTE can be found [here](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/06/simple-family-tree-query-using.html), and try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) for general help with CTE's as they tend to use less-than-standard SQL syntax